# Spark- Load data frame contents in table in a loop

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I use scala/ spark to insert data into a Hive parquet table as follows

```
for(*lots of current_Period_Id*){//This loop is on a result of another query that returns multiple rows of current_Period_Id
  val myDf = hiveContext.sql(s"""SELECT columns FROM MULTIPLE TABLES WHERE period_id=$current_Period_Id""")
  val count: Int = myDf.count().toInt
  if(count>0){
    hiveContext.sql(s"""INSERT INTO destinationtable PARTITION(period_id=$current_Period_Id) SELECT columns FROM MULTIPLE TABLES WHERE period_id=$current_Period_Id""")
  }
}
```

This approach takes a lot of time to complete because the select statement is being executed twice.

I'm trying to avoid selecting data twice and one way I've thought of is writing the dataframe **myDf** to the table directly.

This is the gist of the code I'm trying to use for the purpose

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("myApp")
                             .set("spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead","4096")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)

hiveContext.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition","true")
hiveContext.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
for(*lots of current_Period_Id*){//This loop is on a result of another query
  val myDf = hiveContext.sql("SELECT COLUMNS FROM MULTIPLE TABLES WHERE period_id=$current_Period_Id")
  val count: Int = myDf.count().toInt
  if(count>0){
    myDf.write.mode("append").format("parquet").partitionBy("PERIOD_ID").saveAsTable("destinationtable")
  }
}
```

But I get an error in the *myDf.write* part.

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: period_id
```

The destination table is partitioned by period_id.

Could someone help me with this?

The spark version I'm using is 1.5.0-cdh5.5.2.

Comment: what is output for `myDf.schema` and `describe destinationtable` in hive ?

Comment: @FaigB Sorry for the late reply. I got this in spark shell

org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(ac_name,StringType,true), StructField(ac_time,StringType,true), StructField(ac_hhold,StringType,true), StructField(ac_shop,StringType,true), StructField(ac_barcode,StringType,true), StructField(nc_nan_key,DoubleType,true)...

For describe destinationTable, I got

ac_name                string
ac_time                 string
ac_hhold                string
ac_shop                 string
ac_barcode              string
nc_nan_key              double

Comment: @FaigB contd..  

`# Partition Information  

# col_name              data_type               comment  

period_id         bigint`

Comment: As for myDF.schema show that period_id not exists in dataframe schema and due to that it arises exception

Comment: The exact results are  
`myDf.schema  

StructType(StructField(ac_name,StringType,true),  
StructField(ac_time,StringType,true),  
StructField(ac_hhold,StringType,true),  
StructField(ac_shop,StringType,true),  
StructField(barcode,StringType,true),  
StructField(man_key,DoubleType,true),  
StructField(trip_no,LongType,true),  
StructField(DT_PUR_DATE,StringType,true),  
StructField(_c141,DoubleType,false),  
StructField(_c142,StringType,false),  
StructField(PERIOD_ID,LongType,true))`  

contd..

Comment: ..contd

`describe destinationtable  

ac_audit                string  
ac_time                 string  
ac_hhold                string  
ac_shop                 string  
ac_barcode              string  
nc_nan_key              double  
trip_idx                bigint  
dt_pur_date             string  
nc_tc_factor            double  
fl_is_usable            bigint  
period_id             bigint  
# Partition Information  
# col_name              data_type               comment  
period_id             bigint`

Comment: now it is a bit more clear the PERIOD_ID != period_id column name is Upper case in your DF but in lower case in table. Try in sql with uppercase   the `period_id`

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much. I changed the PERIOD_ID in the query that loads myDf to period_id. Could you write an answer so I can accept it

Comment: already added as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataframe schema and table's description differs from each other. The PERIOD_ID != period_id column name is Upper case in your DF but in UPPER case in table. Try in sql with lowercase the period_id